# prevent google maps loaded multiple times with turbolinks

Tags: javascript, google-maps, ruby-on-rails-5, turbolinks-5

I'm using rails 5 and turbolinks 5, I don't want to disable turbolinks, but it is loading google maps api multiple times.

I've searched a lot, and I found lots of solutions for rails 4 and turbolinks 3. I tried all the solutions I saw but none of them worked.

One of them looks simply:

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp" type="text/javascript" data-turbolinks-eval="always"></script>
```

but still loading google maps multiple times.

Another one of them was:

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp" type="text/javascript" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
```

but is neither working.

A promising solution was:

```
var ready;
ready = function() {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp';
    document.body.appendChild(script);
};

$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', ready);
```

but this one sometimes is not loading google maps before the map inits and sometimes it is returning the error of multiple loads.

I read a lot, there's a lot of questions asking the same, but I don't find a working solution in any of them.

PD: I see now that I deleted the api key of google maps, it is still working but I read an error message in console.

```
Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys
```

Will be any problem if I use google maps without api key in production?

Comment: I don't see a key in those requests.  Keys are now required, it might work (if your site is "grandfathered" for keyless access), but it might also stop working at any time (if google decides to change their grandfathering policy)

Comment: I have the api key and I use it, but I deleted it and I saw that it kept working. That's why I asked ;) Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I solved it, it seems that it is not a good idea to place the javascripts at the end of the body, as I was doing.

In turbolinks 5 documentation it is said to place it on the `<head>`.

Now I placed the scripts on the head and it seems it's working without problem, and I see no multiple loads messages for google maps api.

Comment: which script variant did you put in the head?